Error with bootstrap pagination in production with livewire 3. View [Bootstrap] not found
I have a project created in laravel 10 and livewire 3.
My project works perfectly locally when I deployed it on a shared domain I had the error with pagination.
View [Bootstrap] not found.
This is where I get the error
{{ $archivos->onEachSide(1)->links() }}

in my livewire.php file
'pagination_theme' => 'Bootstrap',

I hope you can help me, best regards
